# Cannot call a function from iterated part of html in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a code where I am looping through elements in an array in reactjs.
For each element I have a delete button, which should remove the element from the db.
When compiling, the code throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Here is my jsx:

```
{(zakazani.map((termin, key) => (
    <tr key={key+1} className="border-t-2 border-b-2 py-4 bg-slate-100 border-slate-200">
         <td className="pl-4 border-r-2 border-slate-200">{key+1}</td>
         <td className="pl-4 border-r-2 border-slate-200">{termin.name}</td>
         <td className="pl-4 border-r-2 border-slate-200">{termin.phone}</td>
         {(termin.time >= 1000) ? (
            <td className="pl-4 border-r-2 border-slate-200">
                {Math.floor(termin.time / 100)}:{termin.time % 100} - {((termin.time % 100 >= 15) ? Math.floor(termin.time / 100) + 1 : Math.floor(termin.time / 100))}:{(termin.time % 100 + 45) % 60}
            </td>
         ) : (
            <td className="pl-4 border-r-2 border-slate-200">
                {Math.floor(termin.time / 100)}:{termin.time % 100} - {((termin.time % 100 >= 15) ? Math.floor(termin.time / 100) + 1 : Math.floor(termin.time / 100))}:{(termin.time % 100 + 45) % 60}
            </td>
         )}
         <td className="pl-2">
            <button 
            onDoubleClick={deleteOne(termin.time, termin.id)}
            className="text-white bg-sky-600 w-10 h-10 flex justify-center px-1 pt-3 rounded-sm mt-2 mb-1 shadow-sm shadow-sky-200"><FaTrash /></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
)))}
```

And here is my deleteOne function:

```js
 const deleteOne = (time, uid) => {
       
        const ref = doc(db, 'zakazeniTermini', uid)
        const ref2 = doc(db, 'termini', time.toString())
        deleteOne(ref)
        updateDoc(ref2, {
            slobodniKreveti: increment(1)
        })
   
       const newArray = zakazani.filter(termin => termin.id !== uid)
       setZakazani(newArray)
    }
```

EDIT: I get the error for both parameters in the function.

Thanks in advance for helping :)

Comment: There is no `indexOf` in the code you've provided. The typeError you're showing must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: The error also says: ```at deleteOne (Tabela.jsx:62:1)```
That line is the following: ``` const ref = doc(db, 'zakazeniTermini', uid) ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you're passing `null` (or `undefined`) to the `doc` call somewhere. Most likely it's your `uid` variable that is `null`, but you should check all variables before using then:

```
const deleteOne = (time, uid) => {      
    if (!uid) throw `deleteOne requires a uid value, but you passed '${uid}'.`
    if (!time || !time.toString) throw `deleteOne requires a time value that implements toString(), but you passed '${time}'.` 

    ...
}
```